# Reading and printing matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix

Ok so my main goal is to multiply two matrices.Before jumping there i proposed myself to write 2 functions to read and display a matrix. Basic stuff i thought.
After i run the program and i enter the number of lines and columns,i can only enter 1 value before it crashes. 
I use Dev c++.
What could the issue be here? Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXSIZE 20
void readM(int M[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE],int,int);
void printM(int M[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE],int,int);

int main ()

{
    int NL,NC,i,j;
    int M[20][20];
    readM(M[20][20],NL,NC);
    printM(M[20][20],NL,NC);    


    return 0;
}


void readM(int M[20][20],int NL,int NC) 
    {
        int i,j;
        printf("Type in number lines ");
        scanf("%d",&NL);
        printf("Type in number of columns ");
        scanf("%d",&NC);
        printf("Type in values \n");

        for(i=0;i<NL;i++)
            {
                for(j=0;j<NC;j++)
                {
                    scanf("%d",&M[i][j]);
                }
            }
    }

void printM(int M[20][20],int NL,int NC)
    {
        int i,j;
        printf("Matrix is \n");

        for(i=0;i<NL;i++)
            {
                for(j=0;j<NC;j++)
                {
                    printf("\t%d\t",M[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
    }
```

Comment: When you call readM just pass M, not M[20][20].

Comment: You should properly format your code to avoid confusion and encourage people to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when you call `readM` and `printM`, you should call them using `M`, not `M[20][20]`.

Then, there's the lines and columns problem. When you pass the arguments `NL` and `NC` to `readM`, you're passing a copy of their values inside `main`. When you read the values in `readM` you'll store what you read locally, and `main` will never know about it.

To change that, you could use pointers or you could read the lines and columns in `main`, leaving `readM` with the sole purpose of reading matrix itens.

The program may be skipping your input because there's trash in the input buffer. The best way of getting user input is creating a custom function that reads whatever there is in `stdin`, and then treat it accordingly. Because you never know what users will input...

Here's the code with my suggestions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXSIZE 20

void readM(int M[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE], int, int);
void printM(int M[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE], int, int);

/* very simple function to treat user input */
int read_num(void)
{
    char buf[50];
    fgets(buf, 50, stdin);
    return atoi(buf);
}

/* if main() won't take any arguments, use void */
int main(void)
{
    int NL, NC, i, j;
    int M[20][20];

    /* extracted from readM */
    printf("Type in number lines ");
    NL = read_num();
    printf("Type in number of columns ");
    NC = read_num();

    readM(M, NL, NC);

    printM(M, NL, NC);


    return 0;
}


void readM(int M[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE], int NL, int NC)
{
    int i, j;
    printf("Type in values \n");

    for (i = 0; i < NL; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < NC; j++) {
            M[i][j] = read_num();
        }
    }
}

void printM(int M[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE], int NL, int NC)
{
    int i, j;
    printf("Matrix is \n");

    for (i = 0; i < NL; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < NC; j++) {
            printf("\t%d\t", M[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so, first: the method with pointers if probably more difficult right?And secondly, can you please give me some hints what you did in the reading function? I mean what's buf and atoi(buf)? and what did that fgets do?

Comment: @CatalinGhita Not that much more difficult. But I didn't know if you know pointers or not, so I chose to not use them.

Comment: Yes i am still learning about them. I added something to my comment,if have time please explain @Enzo Ferber

Comment: @CatalinGhita `buf` is a `char` buffer, where the function `fgets` will store what it reads from `stdin`. A string is a sequence of characters, like this paragraph. `stdin` is the standard way by which programs get their input. `scanf` does that, you just don't see it. `atoi` converts a string into an integer.

Comment: @CatalinGhita `atoi` is necessary because when you read a string like `"10"`, the program will store it as a sequence of bytes: `[49, 48, 0]` in this case. What `atoi` does is convert this into an integer, i.e. a number we can manipulate using variables of type `int`.

Comment: Oh that's so cool. My teacher didn't cover these things.So therefore that;s why you included stdlib? Oh and i knew that all functions should go after main, why did you place the first function above him ? Or that isn't a ferm rule?

Comment: @CatalinGhita Yes, `stdlib.h` is required for `atoi`. No, the order in which you put your functions is not a rule. If you need to call functions before you  **define** them, you must first **declare** them. That's why you have those *function prototypes* at the beginning. If you don't put them there, the compiler will complain about it. It's all a matter of taste. But in college, you should follow your teacher's taste...

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Now i noticed that you didn't write the prototype of the read_num in the first place. So you did that accordingly to your order of functions? I mean could i have placed it below the other 2 functions? obviosly after declaring the prototype in the beggining

Comment: @CatalinGhita Yes, if you declare it's prototype before calling it, you're fine. But if you put `read_num` definition after your other 2 functions and _do not declare it_, your compiler will complain about it.

Comment: @CatalinGhita In fact, if you put your main function in the end of the file, you may remove both prototypes and the compiler won't complain.

Comment: Oh thank you very much. One more question, what would happen if i would type instead of an integer a character? like 'a'. What would it return ? asking because of those new notions for me

Comment: @CatalinGhita Returns zero. But questions like those are the kind of questions that you should try answering by **tinkering** with the code. Put all kinds of input in it, try to make it break, change one line, change the size of the buffer, put a huge input. That will teach more than a thousand books. Tinkering is the hacker's spirit! ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. helped me a lot. Still don't know why i got a downvote..

Comment: @CatalinGhita Don't worry about that. Just keep coding. Keep learning. ;)